# Integrating JavaScript web plugin in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic2, applozic

Im trying to integrate [Applozic](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin) chat platform to my Ionic 2 project, which I wish to export to Web, Android and iOS. Using the [sample](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin/blob/master/src/sample/fullview.html) as a base and created the [applozic.d.ts & applozichv.js](https://gist.github.com/funkyidol/bfed20368d8e5db55b6a2c04dfbb6c1a) for the Javascript integration process.

*applozic.d.ts*

```
interface AppLozicStatic {
    initPlugin(): any;
}

declare var AppLozic : AppLozicStatic;
export = AppLozic;
```

*applozichv.js*

```
(function () {
    var root = this;

    var AppLozic = function (obj) {
        if (obj instanceof AppLozic) return obj;
        if (!(this instanceof AppLozic)) return new AppLozic(obj);
        // this.EXIFwrapped = obj;
    };

    if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
            exports = module.exports = AppLozic;
        }
        exports.AppLozic = AppLozic;
    } else {
        root.AppLozic = AppLozic;
    }

    AppLozic.initPlugin = function () {
        var $original;
        // var $applozic = "";
        var $applozic;
        console.log("initPlugin");

        $original = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        $ = $original;
        jQuery = $original;


        if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
            console.log("initPlugin 1");


            $applozic = jQuery.noConflict(true);

            $applozic.fn
                .applozic({

                    baseUrl : 'https://apps.applozic.com',
                                    userId : 'debug454545', //TODO: replace userId with actual UserId
                                    userName : 'test',          //TODO: replace userId with actual UserName
                                        appId : 'applozic-sample-app',
//                        accessToken: 'suraj',                             //TODO: set user access token.for new user it will create new access token

                    ojq: $original,
                    // obsm: oModal,

                    //optional, leave it blank for testing purpose, read this if you want to add additional security by verifying password from your server https://www.applozic.com/docs/configuration.html#access-token-url
                    //  authenticationTypeId: 1,    //1 for password verification from Applozic server and 0 for access Token verification from your server
                    //  autoTypeSearchEnabled : false,
                    //  messageBubbleAvator: true,
                    notificationIconLink: "https://www.applozic.com/resources/images/applozic_icon.png",
                    notificationSoundLink: "",
                    readConversation: readMessage, // readMessage function defined above
                    onInit: onInitialize, //callback function execute on plugin initialize
                    maxAttachmentSize: 25, //max attachment size in MB
                    desktopNotification: true,
                    locShare: true,
                    video: true,
                    topicBox: true,
//                        mapStaticAPIkey: "AIzaSyCWRScTDtbt8tlXDr6hiceCsU83aS2UuZw",
//                        googleApiKey: "AIzaSyDKfWHzu9X7Z2hByeW4RRFJrD9SizOzZt4" // replace it with your Google API key
                    // initAutoSuggestions : initAutoSuggestions //  function to enable auto suggestions
                });
        }
        var oModal = "";

        /*if (typeof $original !== 'undefined') {
            $ = $original;
            jQuery = $original;
            if (typeof $.fn.modal === 'function') {
                oModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
            }
        } else {
            $ = $applozic;
            jQuery = $applozic;
            if (typeof $applozic.fn.modal === 'function') {
                oModal = $applozic.fn.modal.noConflict();
            }
        }*/

        //Sample json contains display name and photoLink for userId


        function readMessage() {
            //console.log(userId);
        }


        //callback function execute after plugin initialize.
        function onInitialize(response, data) {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                // $applozic.fn.applozic('loadContacts', {'contacts':contactsJSON});
                // $applozic.fn.applozic('loadTab', 'shanki.connect');
                //write your logic exectute after plugin initialize.
                alert("success");
            } else {
                alert(response.errorMessage);
            }
        }


        // init();

    };


})();
```

I added all the above created files including `applozic.common.js`, `applozic.fullview.js` and `jquery.min.js` to the `assets/js` folder and linked them in my `index.html`. This was the only way I could get the JavaScript method in `applozic.js` to execute from my `chat.ts`.

The problem that i'm now facing is the I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined` in `applozic.js`
```

on the line

```
$original = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

and consequently the rest of the if block is also not executing.

In an attempt to make jQuery work in the project I tried to install it via NPM by executing the following commands:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

But this led to issue in `ionic serve` giving the following error:

```
JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I really need help in executing my `applozic.js` file to initialize and call the chat plugin functions.

Comment: Try adding "import {} from '@types/jquery';" and after all imports add "declare var jQuery: any;" . Remember .. add these lines without the quotes.

Comment: @vsoni that's nonsense. Importing from any `@types` package is always invalid.

Comment: That is some very, very suspicious code. While installing `jQuery` was a good idea, it may not help you since the library you are using ships with its own version of `jQuery`. This is unlikely to end well given the official sample contains code you absolutely should not write. For example, `$original = jQuery.noConflict(true); $ = $original;` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad for the feedback. Can you point out what best can be done to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should first identify the actual problem.

If problem is in jquery installation, then you can debug it using following line.

`console.log("Jwuery Text : " , $('.testClassName'));`

If below `log` is completely printed in the console then there is no mistake in `jquery`.

This memory size issue is resolved using `reInitialize` memory heap by using this command :

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
or
node --max_old_space_size=4096
```

After this command run into the command prompt, try to serve project or build a project.